# Depreciating repetition after each set

Tags: exercise, reps, sets

I am doing jump lunges as one of my exercise(. I read online that you should be able to do 8-12 reps in 4-5 sets with 45-60 sec rest in between. In the first set I was able to complete 12 jump lunges(excruciating pain), the second set I went down drastically to 5 and after that to 3 and after that my legs just give out when I attempt another jump. Maybe I am doing it wrong somehow or maybe I am just too weak. Does each side of the leg count as one rep or is it after completing both legs does it start to count as one rep?

Side note this also happens when I do push ups 28 reps per set

Are there any solution to this and how do i keep training when I keep failing after the 2-3 sets?

Answer (score 1):

I would agree a fit person should be able to relatively easily do 4-5 sets of 8-12 jumping lunges with a short rest period.

Without some video of you doing the exercise we cannot tell if you are doing It wrong, but it sounds like you are just weak.

Rep counting is whatever you make of it, in my view (and CrossFit's view) every time you move your legs it counts as a rep. If you were doing a standing lunge you might up it to 8 on each leg.

28 reps of press-ups is reasonably good, and is quite high, I wouldn't personally bother going above 20 reps because beyond that you are just building muscle endurance which I don't really care for.

Solution: Use a easier scaled movement. Instead of jumping, just lunge from a standing position and then return to standing straight (step lunge). The more you practice, the better you will become.